# Existe alguma forma de inserir trechos de códigos pré-definidos no Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Gostaria de saber se o Visual Studio possibilita gerir trechos de código para fácil inserção em arquivos durante uma edição. Ou se existe algum *add-on* que faça isso.

Exemplo:

Tenho esse trecho de código que sempre utilizo:

```
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
```

A ideia seria gravar esse trecho de código e inseri-lo facilmente sempre que necessário, com poucos cliques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é possível!

O Visual Studio permite a criação de trechos de código personalizados. Para isso é necessário criar um arquivo XML usando a estrutura pré-definida pelo Visual Studio.

[Veja todos os detalhes no MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms165394.aspx)

Aqui vai um pequeno passo-a-passo de como criar um *snippet* de código personalizado.

1. Abra o menu ***Tools*** e entre em ***Code Snippet Manager*** ou acesse o gerenciador direto pelo atalho <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**K**</kbd> + <kbd>**B**</kbd>
2. Crie um arquivo XML com esta estrutura

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
   <CodeSnippets  
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">  
       <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">  
           <Header>  
               <Title></Title>  
           </Header>  
           <Snippet>  
               <Code Language="">  
                   <![CDATA[]]>  
               </Code>  
           </Snippet>  
       </CodeSnippet>  
   </CodeSnippets>
   ```
3. No atributo `Language` da tag `Code` coloque a linguagem
4. Dentro dos colchetes de `CDATA` coloque o código do *snippet*
5. Salve o arquivo com a extensão `.snippet`
6. Abra o gerenciador (do passo 1) e clique em ***Import***

Answer (score 4):

Sim, é possível. Isto chama-se Code Snippet e tem [extensiva documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Se não for suficiente [existem *plugins* no *marketplace* do VS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=snippet&target=VS&category=Tools&vsVersion=&subCategory=All&sortBy=Relevance).